# Android How to get the root directory from a file (path)

Tags: java, android, filepath, android-file

How do I get the root directory of any path. If i have file path
/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.google.android.talk/Ringtones/, what is the best way for me to return the root directory "storage".

Is the file path always in "/" format, is that safe to split the path based on the character "/" or is there a built in function that I can call?

I need to create a method to return the root files of all the audio files on the android phone.

Here are some paths that I have and I want to start with the root directory and then browse each directory with audio files, so is there any build in method that I can call that will return the first directory?

```
/storage/emulated/0/media/audio/ringtones/abc.mp3
/storage/emulated/0/Music/Various Artists/music.mp3
/storage/emulated/0/new/Artists/test.mp3
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider to be the root directory of the example path you gave?

Comment: the "storage" as the rootpath.

Comment: I don't think you have access to `/storage` directly. `/storage/emulated/0` would be the SD Card

Comment: is all android SD card start with the path /storage/emulated/0? I don't need to access the /storage directly. I need to create a method that contains all audio files and return their root directory.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` is what `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return on a Nexus device. Never hard code the paths since they vary on different devices

Comment: android file system is Linux-based. However, there are a lot of places you cannot access without root permission. Basically, you should not go above what the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` provides

Comment: I think I kind of know how to proceed now. I only need to access files and directories under the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). At first, I thought the "storage" is the root, so it is really "/storage/emulated/0", and all my audio files are below that folder.

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting would work. One way would be to use substring with indexOf.

```
rootPath = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the root folder from ".apk" as follows:

`java.io.File dir = new java.io.File("/storage/emulated/0");`

and, can create subfolders with:

```
void CreateDir() throws IOException {
    java.io.File dir = new java.io.File("/storage/emulated/0/MyApplication");
    dir.mkdir();
}
```

Normally, you must have write permissions to do this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But the problem starts with Android 10 (API level 29) and newer. Each path is `null`.

To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps.