# How can I get the file in the root folder of my android app code via code?

Tags: java, android, file

[image]

I want to get refernce to the config.json file.

Comment: Those files exist on your development machine. They won't be on the Android device/emulator.

Comment: @MikeM. Then how does Firebase gets their info from the similar file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626455/android-how-to-get-the-root-directory-from-a-file-path

Comment: @VibinKumar That is not relevant.

Comment: Is it not possible that you copy it in your assets folder and access it from there ?

Comment: I want to know if this is possible. From assets folder I get the file alright.

Comment: I just had a look, and I see that that's not a Firebase config file, so I guess I misunderstood what you were asking. If you're not trying to access Firebase's json file specifically, then I have to ask what others are asking - why can't you just put your config.json in `assets/`?

Answer (score 1):

Change location file config.json and put file into "res/raw" folder. By default "raw" folder isn't create in android proyect (you must create it mannually).

In summary, put your json file in "res/raw/config.json". Later, you can read this file in code using next function:

```
public String streamToString(InputStream in) {
    String l;
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((l = r.readLine()) != null) {
            s.append(l);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Now, you can use the previous function to read any file of your res folder. In this case you can use next code to read "config.json" and get a string with the content of file:

```
//Function getResources() must be called from a Context Activity or Aplication
InputStream rawResourceConfig = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config);
String contentConfig = streamToString(rawResourceConfig);
```

Now, you have into contentConfig all content from file config.js as String.

Finally, you can use a GSON library (for example) to convert JSON string to Java Object.

I hope this was hopefully.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the file in the root folder of my android app code via code?

You don't. The build tools do not package random files from random locations into your APK. That `config.json` file is not in your APK.

Use `assets/` or `res/raw/` to package arbitrary content with your app.